# What is a clean way to call a function using several Getters from Control.Lens.

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens

Given some data structure with lenses defined, for example:

```
import Control.Lens

data Thing =
  Thing {
    _a :: String
  , _b :: String
  , _c :: Int
  , _d :: Int
  }

makeLenses ''Thing
```

And given some function that I want to call using several getters, for example:

```
fun :: Int -> String -> Int -> String -> Bool
fun = undefined
```

At the moment, I end up with a lot of ugliness with parens to access each field, for example:

```
thing = Thing "hello" "there" 5 1

answer = fun (thing^.c) (thing^.a) (thing^.d) (thing^.b)
```

Given the conciseness of the `lens` library in most other situations I was hoping for something a little more elegant, but I can't find any combinators that will help this specific case.

Comment: For something like this, it might be better to use `RecordWildCards`. Then you can write `answer (Thing{..}) = fun c a d b`

Comment: You could gain a very small advantage by using the `(->)` `Applicative` instance. Something like `thing & fun <$> view c <*> view a <*> view d <*> view b`. That might be said to express the intention somewhat more directly?

Comment: @ChrisDueck Thanks, but the lenses don't always equate directly to records. Definitely a nice hint when possible though.

Comment: @tel That is pretty much what I am looking for. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since any lens could be used in either the viewing or the setting "mode", we'll need to at least specify `view X` for each lens X. But for any lens `l :: Lens' a b`, `view l` has a type like `a -> b` if you translate some of the `MonadReader` noise.

We can thus get rid of some of the repetition using the `Applicative` instance for `((->) a)`.

```
thing & fun <$> view c <*> view a <*> view d <*> view b
```